# Как получить ключ родительского массива по значению ключа вложенного в него массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется такая структура массива:

```
  ['title' => 'name1',
   'id' => 1,
   'children' => 
      ['title' => 'name2',
       'id' => 2,
       'children' => 
          ['title' => 'name3',
           'id' => 3,
           'children' => []
          ]
      ]
  ],
  ['title' => 'name4',
   'id' => 4,
   'children' => 
      ['title' => 'name5',
       'id' => 5,
       'children' => []
      ]
  ]
```

И, например, нужно по id = 3 получить ключ родительского массива (где id = 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
     $data=array (array('title' => 'name1',
       'id' => '1', 'children' => array('title' => 'name2','id' =>'2', 
        'children' => array('title' => 'name3', 'id' =>'3', 'children' => array()))),
      array('title' => 'name4',
       'id' => 4,
       'children' => 
          array('title' => 'name5',
           'id' => 5,
           'children' => array()
          )
      ));

    $row=count($data);


    for ($i=0; $i <$row ; $i++) {


    if($data[$i]['children']['children']['id']=='3'){

    echo 'Родительский ID= ';  
    print_r($data[$i]['id']);

    }elseif($data[$i]['children']['id']=='3'){
 echo 'Родительский ID= ';  
    print_r($data[$i]['id']);

}

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Сам массив и вложенности не фиксированы, может быть сколько угодно вложений и какие угодно id. Поэтому такой метод в лоб не пройдет

Comment: Сколько минимум ID в ветке ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```php
<?php
$Arr =   [['title' => 'name1',
    'id' => 1,
    'children' =>
        ['title' => 'name2',
            'id' => 2,
            'children' =>
                ['title' => 'name3',
                    'id' => 3,
                    'children' => []
                ]
        ]
],
  ['title' => 'name4',
      'id' => 4,
      'children' =>
          ['title' => 'name5',
              'id' => 5,
              'children' => []
          ]
  ], 
    ['title' => 'name4',
        'id' => 7,
        'children' =>
            ['title' => 'name5',
                'id' => 3,
                'children' => []
            ]
    ],
    ['title' => 'name4',
        'id' => 15,
        'children' =>
            ['title' => 'name5',
                'id' => 15,
                'children' => []
            ]
    ]];


$res = array();

function getLastID ($arr, $needle, $key, $idd){
    if($arr['children'] != null and $arr['id'] != $needle){
        getLastID($arr['children'], $needle, $key, $idd);
    } else {
        $id = $arr['id'];
        if ($id == $needle){
            print_r("В массиве №".$key." Найден ключ ".$idd." значения ".$needle.'<br>');
        } else {
            print_r("В массиве №".$key." Ключ значения ".$needle." не найден<br>");
        }
    }
};

$search = "3"; // Здесь цифра, которую ищем.
foreach ($Arr as $key=>$value){
    $valZ = print_r(getLastID($value, $search, $key, $value['id']));
}
```